# XAML DockPanel won't stretch two Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two buttons added to a dock panel.  The first one only takes up enough room to fit the text 'Save', and the second one stretches to fill the rest of the area provided by the cell grid.  So, the 'Save' button's width is tiny, and the 'Cancel' button's width is huge.

How do I get them to fill the space evenly?

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" >  
    <Button Content="Save"                           
            Margin="5"></Button>
    <Button Content="Cancel"                          
            Margin="5"></Button>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather use a `Grid` with `*` columns for this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Save"                           
            Margin="5"></Button>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Cancel"                          
            Margin="5"></Button>

</Grid>
```

Comment: The dock panel is already in a grid.  In column position 1, I have it defined as Width="*"

Comment: And, the second button is stretching to take up all the room.  If I remove the second button, the first button stretches to take up all the room.  The problem occurs when I add both buttons.

Comment: You can put a second Grid in place of the DockPanel

Comment: It is not a problem to have a Grid inside a Grid :-). The DockPanel is just not suited to create equally sized columns whereas Grid is perfect for this

Comment: UniformGrid would be simpler

Comment: UniformGrid great solution as well, great reminder :-)!

Comment: Thanks @MartinZikmund.  I'll go into the office tomorrow and try it out.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a bunch Martin!

Comment: Sure thing :-) ! Happy coding!